# How to replace ~ (tilde) in vim

Tags: vim, replace

I have a string with a ~ in it and using the expression

Example:

```
hi~how~are~you

:%s/~/ /g
```

This doesn't seem to work any ideas?

Comment: Doh! guess I need more coffee this morning.  That should have occured to me.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The symbol `~` matches the previous substitute string (see `:help /~`), so you need to prefix it with a backslash:

```
:%s/\~/ /g
```

Comment: Thank you for also showing what the tilde does and how to look up it's help info.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to escape it with a backslash:

```
:%s/\~/ /g
```

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/\~//g
```

Need to use a backslash for the tilde.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else copies a tilde from, e.g., microsoft word, you might also need to search for character 8764 / Hex 223c / Octal 21074 (the ascii tilde is 126/Hex 7e/Octal 176).  You can enter that by typing `<ctrl-V> u 223c` (see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters for details on entering character codes)