# VIM find and substitute with ~ and \r

Tags: vim

I'm currently working on a latex file with a lot of `\ref{}`. Using vim, I want to replace every `\ref` by `~\ref`, however, I can't figure out a pattern that match exactly what I want, the `f` is missing whatever pattern I use. I've tried each type of magic with the pattern `\\ref`, but nothing works.

Moreover, even if I try to replace just `\re`, I can't get rid off the `\r` behavior in the command `:%s//~\\re/g`, am I missing something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace ~ (tilde) in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460534/how-to-replace-tilde-in-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just experimenting and I found that escaping both the `~` and the `\` worked, so:

```
the quick
brown \ref{} fox
\ref{} jumps over \ref{}
the lazy dog
```

with:

```
:%s/\\ref/\~\\ref/g
```

resulted in:

```
the quick
brown ~\ref{} fox
~\ref{} jumps over ~\ref{}
the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably coming from `~` which also has a special meaning as pointed out in the other answer by DaveyDaveDave. A little tip is to always search the help for `/` + your sequence to find its regex meaning. Like `:h /~` or `:h /\r`.

Regarding

```
:%s//~\\re/g
```

This command is problematic since it just searches for the previous pattern (the search is empty, `//`) and also replaces with an unescaped `~` which is not what you want.

Shorter ways of doing achieving this:

```
:%s/\\ref/\~&/g
:%s/\ze\\ref/\~/g
```