# vim substitute strange chars on printf after rsync

Tags: c, regex, vim, macvim

I edited (macvim) file.c here and then rsync it to the server. When I ssh in the linux machine and vim file.c I notived strange chars. In all printf, `"` changed to `?~@~\` in the left side and to `?~@~]` in the right side.

```
printf("text");
```

appears as

```
printf(?~@~\text?~@~]);
```

I tried to :substitute

```
:s/\<?~@~\\>/"
```

But it didn't changed and I got

```
E486: Pattern not found: \<?~@~\\>
```

What might be the approach to that substitution?

Comment: could you tell why you are using word boundary `\<` ? `\\>` will be treated as backslash and `>`, you'd need `\\\>` to mean backslash and word boundary... `~` also requires escaping for some reason

Comment: In fact no, I can't tell, should I try `s/\<?\~@\~\\\>/"`?

Comment: no, using word boundary won't work for the given sample..  try `s/?\~@\~\\/"`

Comment: same thing E486

Comment: in that case, probably `?~@~` are not literal but some kinda representation? like `^M` for carriage return?

Comment: Your macvim has a plugin that replaces quotes with "smart quotes". You cannot replace them with normal quotes with sed because there are no literal ? @ and ] characters there. It's just vim on your Linux side being unable to display UTF-8 characters. Remove the plugin, fix the file on the mac side. You may also want fix your Linux setup so that it understands Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

In `vim`, `~` is a symbol for the last given substitute string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460572/3741713). You need to escape it.

The following will replace `?~@~\`:
`:%s/?\~@\~\\/"`
And for the 2nd expression `?~@~]`:
`:%s/?\~@\~]/"`

NB use `:%s` to substitute in the whole file.